# OleDbException: Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: .net, sql, ms-access

I read data from MS Access using C#. But get the OleDbException trying to execute such query:

```
SELECT * FROM Flats 
WHERE Flats.VersionStamp <= [theDate] AND Flats.Flat=[theFlat]
```

OleDbException:

```
Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

On the other side, any one of the following queries works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM Flats 
WHERE Flats.VersionStamp <= [theDate] AND Flats.Flat=1

SELECT * FROM Flats 
WHERE Flats.VersionStamp <= #1/1/2009# AND Flats.Flat=[theFlat]
```

The C# code stays the same all the time:

```
DbParameter theFlat = new OleDbParameter("theFlat", 1);
DbParameter theDate = new OleDbParameter("theDate", new DateTime(2009, 1, 1));

using (DbDataReader reader = dbHelper.ExecuteReader(sqlText, theFlat, theDate))
{ }
```

Finally, the query can be successfully executed directly in the MS Access UI.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but I don't think the OleDb classes support named parameters.  Try the following SQL instead:

```
SELECT * FROM Flats WHERE Flats.VersionStamp <= ? AND Flats.Flat=?
```

The parameters must be added to the command object in the right order (I don't see you adding the parameters in your code).

Comment: Depending on the underlying db it talks to, Ole allows named parameters but just doesn't use the names: you still have to line them up by order.

Comment: AFAIK  , OleDb supports named parameters, but not completely.  You can give names to the parameters, but, you indeed need to add them in the correct order to the command - object.

Comment: Thank you, Joel & Frederik. I changed the parameters order in ExecuteReader(...) and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you defining/using the parameters in your SQL String; I don't see them.

Try this:

```
SELECT * From Flats WHERE VersionStamp = @theDate AND Flat = @theFlat

DbParameter = new OleDbParameter ("@theDate", someDate);
```

Comment: [theDate] and [theFlat] works for me as well as @theDate and @theFlat.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;316744

> Contrary to what the preceding
>   documentation error describes, the
>   OleDbCommand parameters are positional
>   when they are used with the Microsoft
>   SQL Server OLE DB provider. The names
>   of the parameters can be arbitrary...
>   The order of the parameters that you
>   add to the OleDbParameterCollection
>   must match the order of the parameters
>   in your stored procedure.