# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access, oledb

This is my code:

```
OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
Cmd.Connection = MyConn;
Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM catalogue WHERE id = '" + questionid + "'";

OleDbDataReader read = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

int id = 0;

while (read.Read())
{
    id = Convert.ToInt32(read["id"]);
}
```

Here's the error it gives me:

```
Line 27:         Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM catalogue WHERE id = '" + questionid + "'";
Line 28: 
Line 29:         OleDbDataReader read = Cmd.ExecuteReader(); // The error is here
Line 30: 
Line 31:         int id = 0;
```

I know there is also [another question about the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650282/oledbexception-data-type-mismatch-in-criteria-expression) on Stack Overflow, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem (it may solve yours, so I put a link).

Comment: could you point out at which line it throws the exception? the code seems to be fine.

Comment: Is `questionid`  and `id` in `catalogue ` are of same/equivalent datatype. If so make sure questionid  is not null. Nice point by @nvoigt, you should use parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please learn about [using blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yh598w02.aspx) for all your disposibles, that includes database connection, command and readers.

Your code is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you may want to fix that by using parameters.

Finally, I suspect your id field in the database is of integer type, so using quotes around the value is a mistake. But please read up on parameters instead of fixing that. Parameters will get rid of that problem anyway.

Comment: It was indeed of integer type. And that's something I've learnt today! Thank you!

Comment: @think123 in fact your query is very OK if it's a `SQL Server query`, I've not experienced enough with OleDb but its behavior is a little annoying.

Comment: @KingKing Yeah, but I'm stuck with access. I came from MySQL, so I wasn't very familiar with such strict rules.